# std::cosf fluctuation: Results are off in low frequencies

Tags: digital-communications, continuous-signals, digital-filters, downsampling, complex

I attempted to generate a continuous wave signal by using the C++ cos/sin functions. It's partly successful, meaning high frequencies seems ok, but very low frequencies give unexpected results. The very brief part of the code is below, only used std libraries.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <fstream>

const float _scale = 30000;
const float _2pi = 2 * std::acosf(-1);

int main()
{
    int len = 1e3;
    auto iq = new std::complex<short>[len];
    float foff = 0.001f;
    float phase_step = _2pi * foff;
    for (int n = 0; n < len; n++)
    {
        float phase = phase_step * n;
        phase -= (int)(phase / _2pi) * _2pi; // take multiple of 2pi
        iq[n].real(_scale * std::cosf(phase));
        iq[n].imag(_scale * std::sinf(phase));
    }

    std::ofstream ofile("cw.iq");
    ofile.write((char*)&iq[0], sizeof(short) * len * 2);
    ofile.close();
}
```

Also, a figure of iq array is below. So, my questions

1. What causes this issue
2. How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for taking the time.

[image]

I've added full code. You can re-produce error and have a look at the output file, "cw.iq". It is interleaved complex data, short integer each element: IQIQIQ...

Comment: Most likely, quantization issues due to the limited precision of floating-point calculations

Comment: Try using cos and not cosf and use doubles

Comment: @ben, nah, quantization shouldn't happen at *these* scales, really. I mean, really, single-precision floating point has the equivalent of ca 16 significant decimal digits. That's not what's wrong here.

Comment: @ben, double didn't help. I tried it out already. My idea is in small phases cosinus is jumping from positive to negative or reverse versa, but could find a solution yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem that /can't be reproduced)[https://imgur.com/a/CMgqIq5], even using OP's code in a [quick test fixture](https://gist.github.com/224c26b3d1009e72fdb0dce6deb040e0). Therefore, it has to be a programming mistake somewhere else (not all code is shown), and that would render this borderline question definitely off-topic for this site, anyways.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I added full code, now you can re-produce error.

Comment: still can't reproduce. [Works beautifully](https://i.imgur.com/UR30WdJ.png), so problem is on your side or in your plotting code. Again, programming problems aren't on-topic here, signal processing is.

Comment: @Abdullah Your graph doesn't make sense. Amplitude should be 30000 but your graph shows an amplitude of 1.

Comment: Yep, Abdullah, this is a problem somewhere in your code, and that includes the plotting code.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks a lot! After you point out the plotting tool, I found the issue. It is file writing. The one I used before is for char writing. I replaced it with binary writing, then it's solved. 
std::ofstream ofile("cw.iq", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary); 
The case progressed a little weird as I found no issues at some frequencies. Then I focused on cos/sin functions, but actually it's ended-up with file writing :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's OP's mistake, not a DSP problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue was in the file writing, signal created correctly with the code.

```
std::ofstream ofile("cw.iq", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);   
ofile.write((char*)&iq[0], sizeof(short) * len * 2);
ofile.close();
```